# fgrep -f pattern.txt return the eaxct pattern in pattern.txt

Tags: linux, shell

I have a pattern file as shown below

```
$cat pattern.txt
I am line 1
I am line 2
I am line 3
I am line 4
```

the file I want to search:

```
$cat file.txt
I am line 0
I am line 1
I am line 2
I am line 3
I am line 4
I am line 5
I am line 3
I am line 4
```

if I do

```
fgrep -f pattern.txt file.txt I am getting output as
I am line 1
I am line 2
I am line 3
I am line 4
I am line 3
I am line 4
```

But I want the search to return output only if it find lines same as pattern.txt, output should look like as I mentioned below. If the exact match of pattern.txt is not found then it should return nothing.

```
Output:
I am line 1
I am line 2
I am line 3
I am line 4
```

plz help me if there is a way to do this. Appreciate for your help.

Comment: The current output is correct because there are duplicate lines in the file.txt. You're asking for the output to be unique which you can obtain by adding a pipeline like `fgrep -f ... | sort -u`. There is the `uniq` cmd, but it expects the input to be in sorted order, where your example data is not. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

how about this one

perl -ne 'print if ($seen{$_} .= @ARGV) =~ /10$/'  pattern.txt file.txt

Comment: I think I have confused you with my example. Sorry my bad. I basically want to know those four lines in pattern.txt if they are repeated (in same order) in file.txt or not. I consider it duplicate if they are repeated in same oder otherwise not duplicate :)